# MySQL SUM With Grouped Date

Tags: php, mysql, sum, case

How to get data Price with grouped date ?

```
SELECT store.date, store.pic, owner.name, 
SUM (CASE WHEN [>>GROUPED store.date<<] THEN store.price) AS total_price
FROM store
JOIN owner 
ON store.pic = owner.name GROUP BY store.date
```

and i want to display like this :

```
+-------------+------+------------+
| date        | name |  price     | 
+-------------+------+------------+
| 2016-09-30  | John | 100000.00  |
| 2016-09-29  | Rey  | 125000.00  | 
+-------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: show table structure.Otherwise your query is perfect....here is an example: select category_id, 
sum(case when category_id=2 then product_min_price else 0 end) as ss,
sum(case when category_id=1 then product_min_price else 0 end) as ttt

from  myzf.products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this will may help you,

```
 SELECT store.date, store.pic, owner.name,SUM(store.price) AS total_price
 FROM store
 JOIN OWNER ON store.pic = owner.name
 GROUP BY store.date
```

i can't understand why you used case statement in your query